# Cargo Maven Plugin unable to download and unpack Jetty zip due to "Negative seek offset"

Tags: java, maven, jetty, maven-cargo

1. I am facing the below error while running my integration tests:

   ```
   Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2- 
   plugin:1.1.3:start (start-container) on project <project-name>:
   Execution start-container of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-
   plugin:1.1.3:start failed: Error while expanding 
   <project>/target/downloads/jetty-6.1.26.zip
   [ERROR] java.io.IOException: Negative seek offset
   ```

Although, if I just do mvn jetty:run, it does start the server.
Did anybody face similar issue, how did you solve it?

here is the configuration I have :

```
    <plugin>
            <!-- http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <wait>false</wait>
                <container>
                    <containerId>jetty6x</containerId>
                    <!-- The 'embedded' container does not seem to support 
                        setting JNDI values through a jetty-env.xml file, see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CARGO-861 
                        and http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/CARGO-862 for more information. For now, 
                        we'll use the 'installed' container which works fine, it is just slightly 
                        slower than the embedded version since it is a large distribution (25 mb) 
                        that must be downloaded. -->
                    <type>installed</type>
                    <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.zip</url>
                        <downloadDir>${project.build.directory}/downloads</downloadDir>
                        <extractDir>${project.build.directory}/extracts</extractDir>
                    </zipUrlInstaller>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <java.io.tmpdir>target/tmp</java.io.tmpdir>
                        <!-- These "jetty6.*" system properties are used 
                            to set values in the jetty-env.xml file. -->
                        <jetty6.context>Project-NAME</jetty6.context>
                        <jetty6.warFile>${project.build.directory}/project-war.war</jetty6.warFile>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <output>${project.build.directory}/cargo-container.log</output>
                    <log>${project.build.directory}/cargo.log</log>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <location>${project.basedir}/src/test/keystores/sun/${keystoreType}</location>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <home>${project.build.directory}/jetty6x/container</home>
                    <!-- See http://cargo.codehaus.org/Configuration+properties 
                        for possible properties. -->
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.servlet.port>9090</cargo.servlet.port>
                        <cargo.logging>low</cargo.logging>
                        <!-- Enable to debug the server, see http://cargo.codehaus.org/Debugging 
                            for more information. -->
                       <!--  <cargo.jvmargs> -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8888 
                            -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE </cargo.jvmargs> -->
                    </properties>
                    <configfiles>
                        <configfile>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/src/test/keystores/sun/${keystoreType}/jetty-env.xml</file>
                            <todir>contexts</todir>
                            <tofile>project-Name.xml</tofile>
                        </configfile>
                    </configfiles>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <groupId><project-NAME></groupId>
                            <artifactId>project-war</artifactId>
                            <type>war</type>
                            <properties>
                                <context>project-Name</context>
                            </properties>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

2. I know codehaus is going down, eventually will have to update. Any suggestions so to what would be a lightweight server to deploy the war and run integration tests as a client?

Comment: Please use meaningful and descriptive titles. "Jetty unable to" is the worst I've seen

Comment: Looks like a corrupt download. Try re-downloading the zipfile

Comment: This isn't a jetty problem, its a cargo maven-plugin, or maven in general, issue.

Comment: Also note, Jetty 6 was EOL (End of Life) in 2010. [Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 were EOL in 2014](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html).  It is **unsafe** to run Jetty 6 in production on the public internet (running it on private / internal websites with no public internet accessible paths to Jetty is acceptable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The fundamental reason:**

[Codehaus.org](http://www.codehaus.org/) is a dead website.  It will be 100% offline on May 17, 2015.

> The time has come to end the era of Codehaus.
>
> All Codehaus services will be terminated progressively until May 17th
>   2015
>
> With increasing diversity in opensource hosting platforms like Github
>   and Bitbucket - who are meeting the needs of 1000s of projects - it
>   makes sense to end the opensource hosting services of Codehaus.
>
> Codehaus has operated at a loss for several years now (we're not
>   powered by venture capital), and can not compete with the army of
>   developers and integrated product offerings that are now commonplace.
>
> The platform was to be terminated at the end of February 2015, however
>   SonarQube has graciously offered to sponsor Codehaus for a few months
>   to aid in the transition.

Your URL access to dist.codehaus.org is failing.

```xml
<url>http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/jetty-6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.zip</url>
```

**Other Important Notes:**

- There have been 25 releases of `cargo-maven2-plugin` since version 1.1.3, consider upgrading.
- Cargo has moved off of codehaus as well, find them at [codehaus-cargo.github.io](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/) now.
- Don't use Jetty 6, its EOL (End of Life) as of 2010.
- There will not be a replacement download location for Jetty 5 and Jetty 6 binaries that were once hosted on [dist.codehaus.org](http://dist.codehaus.org/).
- Don't use [Jetty 7 or Jetty 8 either, those are EOL as of 2014](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html).
- Jetty 9 is the only stable and supported series of Jetty at this point in time (May 2015).

Comment: yes, I was able to run jetty with an older zip download that I had from one of my other projects. Right now jetty 6x zip does not work. Will need to use some other server. Thanks!!